# trying to mod_rewrite directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

Im trying to mod_rewrite using httpd

I want Source:

```
www.foo.bar.com/abc/
```

to go to Destination:

```
www.foo.bar.com/def/
```

So I've arrived at:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/([^/\.]+).$ def/$1 [L]
```

But i don't only want it for that one page, i want all subsequent pages following the url to rewrite also.

Example `www.foo.bar.com/abc/blahblahblah1.html` to goto  `www.foo.bar.com/def/blahblahblah1.html`

The problem is I don't think this is right, because it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /def/$1
```

Simplified it a little as I'm not sure why you're stopping the rewrite at any given '/' or '.' - could lead to some odd behaviour.

This is assuming you're performing the rewrite in `.htaccess` (in the document root) rather than, say, `httpd-vhosts.conf` (there may be slight differences in the paths between the two).

Comment: `^/abc` will never match anything in a Per Directory context

Comment: Good point - I got it arse about face; leading "/" in vhosts, no leading "/" in .htaccess would be correct.

Comment: Yup, I am lost as to *why* the rewrite engine would remove the `/` in a per dir context bur not otherwise.  I guess it as a dumb decision in history that they can't undo because of backwards compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)   def/$1               [L,NS]
```

This assumes that the `.htaccess` is in your DOCROOT.  Always specify a base -- which is / for your document root.  Do not include the leading / for Per Directory (in `.htaccess`).

Comment: What if this wasn't for .htacces in DOCROOT and apache was simply being used in front of jboss AS?

Comment: OK, which `htaccess` file is this for? The only other one it would work in would be in `DOCROOT/abc/.htaccess`, in which case the base would be `/abc` and the rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)  /def/$1 [L,NS]`